# Why does VBA raise a "type mismatch" error when I use "Format(string_variable, "###.#") and the value of the string_variable is set to 0.0

Tags: excel, string, format, mismatch

My stock-trading code formats price changes (single variable) for transmission to my cell phone and limit the number of insignificant digits. When the price change is zero the module raises a "Type Mismatch" error. All non-zero values work fine.  I have written a simple module which exhibits this behavior.

```vb
Sub test_format()
    Dim test_single As Single, output As String
    test_single = 0#
    output = Str(Format(test_single, "###.#"))
    Debug.Print test_single; output
End Sub
```

Comment: You should not need to apply the str() on the format function as the format function returns a string anyway. If you want to ensure the format only takes a string then encapsulate the variable (test_single in this case) in the Str function. Keep in mind though that Str requires a numeric input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the Str() Function

```vb
Sub test_format()
    Dim test_single As Single, output As String
    test_single = 112.25
    output = Format(test_single, "##0.0")
    Debug.Print output
End Sub
```

My Output:

```
112.3
```

EDIT: Updated the formatting to "##0.0". Now if you get the value 0.0 it won't just return " . " but will actually return 0.0

Comment: That solves the "Type Mismatch" error. However, when I set test_single = 0.0 the output is returned as "." (only the decimal point). I am running Office 365

Comment: Can you try Format(test_single, "###.#0") or "###.#0;"?

Comment: Ok, I found the solution, I think. It is "##0.0". That worked for me and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @JoeSch, if this was the answer for you, I'd really like the UpVote. Thanks